# Creating 'Reactivation' Option in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

I have a problem that I wanted to create a reactivate option for users, but after trying several times, it is not working and I am confused.

here is the middleware (original version):

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (!Auth::check()) {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        } else {
            return redirect()->guest('/');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $user = Auth::user();            
        if (!$user->activated) {
            $activation = action('Auth\AuthController@getActivationMail', ['username' => $user->username]);
            Auth::logout();

            return redirect()->guest('auth')
                    ->withErrors(array('message' => 'Please activate your account. Re-send your activation by clicking <a href=' . $activation . '>here</a>.'));
        }           
        else if (!$user->enabled) {
            Auth::logout();

            return redirect('/auth')->withErrors(array('message' => 'Your account has been deactivated. Please email ... for any inquiries.'))->withInput();
            // I tried to add the same method as the above if statement but not working here
        }

        $user->runDailyNotifications();
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

I wanted to update my database using this way:

```
    $user = Auth::user();
    $user->enabled = 1;
    $user->save();
```

which should be working fine.

I am new to Laravel. At first, I added these code in the middleware (which is a mistake).

After trying a bit I know it is impossible for it to work (when users click login twice they will log in after deactivating their account). Now I'm just wondering how could I achieve that since I kept getting error messages from everywhere. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I have done email confirmation and resend confirmation in one of my older projects. I've done the email confirmation validation in the post login check in the LoginController. Let me post you some snippets which might help you.

```
// Overwrite the authenticated method in LoginController
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if ($user->isBanned()) {
        $this->logout($request);

        flashError('Your account has been banned.');

        return back();
    }

    if (!$user->isEmailConfirmed()) {

        $this->logout($request);

        flashWarning('Email confirmation pending. <a href="'. route('confirm.resend', $user->id) .'">Click here</a> to resend confirmation email.');

        return back();
    }

    return redirect()->route($this->redirectRoute);
}

public function resendConfirmationEmail(Request $request, User $user)
{
    //resend confirmation email
}

public function confirmEmail(Request $request, $token)
{
    // Validate the token and update the user email confirmation status
}
```

Model

```
public function isBanned()
{
    return (bool) $this->banned;
}

public function isEmailConfirmed()
{
    return (bool) $this->confirmed;
}
```

Route

```
Route::get('confirm/resend/{user}', 'Auth\RegisterController@resendConfirmationEmail')->name('confirm.resend');
Route::get('confirm/email/{token}', 'Auth\RegisterController@confirmEmail')->name('confirm.email');
```